# How do you do parallel matrix multiplication in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a good way to do parallel matrix multiplication in julia? I tried using DArrays, but it was significantly slower than just a single-thread multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

Parallel in what sense? If you mean single-machine, multi-threaded, then Julia does this by default as OpenBLAS (the underlying linear algebra library used) is multithreaded.

If you mean multiple-machine, distributed-computing-style, then you will be encountering a lot of communications overhead that will only be worth it for **very** large problems, and a customized approach might be needed.

Comment: after a little bit search through, julialang doc http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/#module-Base.LinAlg, julia source https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/matmul.jl#L333 and lapack source http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f_source.html, at the end I haven't find any sign of parallel computation for matrix manipulation. where is it?

Comment: @RezaAfzalan LAPACK and BLAS from netlib.org are the reference implementations. The mentioned multithreaded implementation is [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/).

Comment: @RezaAfzalan More specifically, the threaded code is in https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/tree/develop/driver/level3

Answer (score 5):

The problem is most likely that direct (maybe single-threaded) matrix-multiplication is normally performed with an optimized library function. In the case of OpenBLAS, this is already multithreaded. For arrays with size `2000x2000`, the simple matrixmultiplication

```
@time c = sa * sb;
```

results in 0.3 seconds multithreaded and 0.7 seconds singlethreaded.

Splitting of a single dimension in multiplication the times get even worse and reach around 17 seconds in singlethreaded mode.

```
@time for j = 1:n
    sc[:,j] = sa[:,:] * sb[:,j]
end
```

#### shared arrays

The solution to your problem might be the use of shared arrays, which share the same data across your processes on a single computer. Please note that shared arrays are still marked as experimental.

```
# create shared arrays and initialize them with random numbers
sa = SharedArray(Float64,(n,n),init = s -> s[localindexes(s)] = rand(length(localindexes(s))))
sb = SharedArray(Float64,(n,n),init = s -> s[localindexes(s)] = rand(length(localindexes(s))))
sc = SharedArray(Float64,(n,n));
```

Then you have to create a function, which performs a cheap matrix multiplication on a subset of the matrix.

```
@everywhere function mymatmul!(n,w,sa,sb,sc)
    # works only for 4 workers and n divisible by 4
    range = 1+(w-2) * div(n,4) : (w-1) * div(n,4)
    sc[:,range] = sa[:,:] * sb[:,range]
end
```

Finally, the main process tells the workers to work on their part.

```
@time @sync begin
    for w in workers()
        @async remotecall_wait(w, mymatmul!, n, w, sa, sb, sc)
    end
end
```

which takes around `0.3 seconds` which is the same time as the multithreaded single-process time.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're interested in dense matrices, in which case see the other answers. Should you be (or become) interested in sparse matrices, see https://github.com/madeleineudell/ParallelSparseMatMul.jl.

Comment: Thank you for your help!